# Can't specify identity column explicitly BUT ALSO can't leave it unspecified

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm hitting a catch 22 here. When I create a new object like so and store it using EF, I get the error.

```
private void DataGrid_OnAddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  eventArgs.NewItem = new Customer
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Discount = 0
  };
}
```

The only identity column in that table is *LookUp* and the error nags about it like so.

> DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

**However** (and this is the 22-catchy spot), when I make sure the value isn't a default nor null as follows, I get another problem.

```
private void DataGrid_OnAddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  eventArgs.NewItem = new Customer
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    LookUp = -1,
    Discount = 0
  };
}
```

And the problem manifests itself as follows.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I'm working with EF and I'm not sure how to set the identity inserting to off. In fact I'm not even sure if it's possible at all. And even if I knew how to, it still seems like **hiding** the problem, not resolving it.

My bet is that I need to be able to omit the specification of the *LookUp* field and still be able to insert the thing into the database. Not sure how, though, and I don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big fan of answering my own questions, especially when the answer I've found is more of a hide-the-issue not resolve-the-issue but here it goes.

1. Remove the whole model (delete EDMX file).
2. Save all files.
3. Clear all files and then rebuild the solution (which will fail miserably).
4. Close the project.
5. Restart VS.
6. Reload the project.
7. Create a new model (add and configure EDMX file).
8. Save all files.
9. Rebuild the solution.

Poof - it works. Weird...

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell EF that you want to generate the value yourself. You can either use data annotations thus:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Customer
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOptions.None)]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  ..
}
```

or by overriding OnModelCreating in your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
  ..
}
```

If you prefer that the database generates the Id for you, you can exchange the       `DatabaseGeneratedOptions.None` to `DatabaseGeneratedOptions.Identity`

Comment: I see your approach. However, I'd prefer **not to** specify the value myself. I'd expect EF to be able to handle that without me doing anything extra in the code. Do you happen to know where in the model, EMDX file etc. that it's specified?

Comment: See my updated answer on how to do it in code. I haven't worked with Model First so I can help you there. If possible for you, I would strongly recommend Code First if you're planning to migrate to EF7 in the future.